# Can anyone explain this vulnerability in PPC

Tags: peercoin

Can anyone explain the vulnerability of PPCoin and possibly other Proof of Stake coins that might allow an attacker to double spend? I've seen one explanation here:

https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=169204.msg1761154#msg1761154

but it wasn't clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PPCoin and other coins use Proof of Stake in addition to Proof of Work.  Stake is how long a coin has been idle multiplied by its value.  If you've been holding many coins for a long time, you can spend their coin age in lieu of poof of work.  The fear is that someone will hoard coins, gather a bunch of age, and then double-spend and use his accrued coin age to give each spend 6 confirmations immediately, without needing CPU work.

It's a valid concern, in my opinion.